# Issue using MSDeploy Web Deploy 4 to Deploy to an Azure App Service from Azure VM

Tags: msbuild, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

We were deploying to An Azure App Service using MSDeploy 4 (not 3.6). Out of nowhere we began getting the following error:

##[error]Error: Error Code: ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED
More Information: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
Error: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.
Error count: 1.

Full Stack Trace:

More Information: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection. Contact your server administrator if the problem persists. Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.

---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()

at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventSerializer.Deserialize(Stream responseStream, DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

--- End of Inner Exception Stack Trace ---

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.StatusThreadHandler.CheckForException()

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageSerializer.CheckForErrorOrCancel()

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageSerializer.SerializeSingleObject(DeploymentObject obj, Int32 parentId)

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageSerializer.Serialize(DeploymentObject obj, Boolean shouldSendPadding)

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObject sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, Nullable`1 syncPass, String syncSessionId)

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)

at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)

at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.ExecuteWorker()

Based on other answers we attempted: disabling windows firewall,disabling windows defender realtime protection. Ensured Fiddler wasn't running. The issue was only happening on our Azure VM's, not from on prem devices.

Finally ran Fiddler which showed digicert.com was being blocked at IP 192.229.211.108 on our firewall.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure traffic is allowed to 192.229.211.108:80 Fiddler was showing 502 bad gateways to digicert.com hosts when trying to negotiate TLS to our app service. After the firewall block was removed the Fiddler log turned into a series of 200's to our app service IP address as expected and the error stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).